# MySQL Query Sorting High Scores

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select the top 3 entries from a table called games that has foreign keys to the players and 2 ints for individual scores for the host and opponent.

The Query:

```
SELECT 
   games.id, games.host_score, games.opponent_score, player.name 
FROM games, player 
WHERE player.id = games.host_player_id 
      || player.id = games.opponent_player_id 
ORDER BY games.host_score, games.opponent_score DESC LIMIT 3
```

The query completes but it comes back out of order:

```
id  host_score  opponent_score  name
17  0           0               Temp2
17  0           0               Temp0
16  770         930             Temp0
```

When I run a query that doesn't have an OR it works. How can I get this method working?

Also is there a way to set a LIMIT of 50 but not count duplicates?
For example if i wanted a limit of 2 but 3 people have the score 50 and 2 people have the score 20 it would return :

```
id  host_score  opponent_score  name
17  50          0               Temp2
17  50          0               Temp0
17  50          0               Temp1
17  20          0               Temp3
17  20          0               Temp4
```

Or would it be better to run it as seperate quesies in php?

Comment: What makes you think that is out of order? (0,0,770) looks like it's increasing order by host score...

Comment: Don't use `||` and `&&`. There is `OR` and `AND` in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to order from highest to lowest, you need to specify it for each field

```
ORDER BY games.host_score DESC, games.opponent_score DESC
```

Because when you don't specify the order it assumes you want the ascending order

Answer (score 0):

You should use OR (instead of ||)  in SQL, also add parenthesis to make it readable.

```
WHERE (player.id = games.host_player_id) OR (player.id = games.opponent_player_id)
```

To get top 50 scores by the score values, though the total row count returned may be higher.
Use the barebones query below and tweak it to your needs.

```
SELECT g1.id, g1.host_scores, COUNT(g2.host_scores) AS Rank
FROM games g1
WHERE Rank <= 50
JOIN games g2 ON (g1.host_scores < g2.host_scores) OR (g1.host_scores=g2.host_scores) 
GROUP BY g1.id, g1.host_scores
ORDER BY g1.host_scores DESC;
```

I must add that for such things to avoid complexity you can also get the data to your
application and easily do this in a programming language like Java, PHP etc. 
It may result in you making more than one query but is far more simpler and more 
maintainable over time.

Comment: That worked lbu thanks and I made that change to OR. @mk I do want the duplicates. I want all the results for the 50 top scores. So there could be more than 50 being returned.

Answer (score 0):

I think your query is wrong, because one game will be on two rows -- one for the host and one for the opponent.

You want to get both the host and opponent names, so you need to join twice to the `player` table:

```
SELECT g.id, g.host_score, g.opponent_score, hp.name as HostName, op.name as OpponentName
FROM games g join
     player hp
     on hp.id = g.host_player_id join
     player op
     on op.id = g.opponent_player_id 
ORDER BY g.host_score, g.opponent_score DESC
LIMIT 3
```

Comment: I agree with @Gordon Linoff, see it in action: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/06faf/42